# Carry Windows user permissions from a previous installation

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8

I reinstalled Windows. As a result, I have lost permissions for some files from my previous installation.

I know how to take ownership or grant permissions.

However, can I not tell Windows somehow that I am the same user? Is there any key or fingerprint which I can copy, or command I can use, to let Windows handle my access rights correctly?

Comment: You could but it would break your new install, would also only be possible, if the new install was an image of the original installtion much easier to simply take ownership of the files

Answer (score 1):

A Windows SID (Security Identifier) consists of a domain part and an object part.

If your Windows is not part of an AD (or even NT) domain, the domain part will be "randomly global unique" for every installation of Windows - you would need to clone the ID from the old installation into the current - there exist tools to do that, but it may or may not be a wise idea.

For the object part, you would need to create a user with the same ID as the one on your old installation - this is quite straight forward and introduces no risks AFAIK.